# How to configure Scheduled pipeline in gitlab yml file?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, schedule

I need to configure .gitlab-ci.yml file in order to run a scheduled pipeline for e2e job only.
I tried to apply that on gitlab UI, but as I can see nothing is running. So my question is, what should I add on the Yml file to make it works ?
Note : I have too many jobs on the yml file but I need to schedule just e2e job.

this is my yml file :

```
e2e:
  stage: test
  <<: *kubernettes-docker
  <<: *test-only
  <<: *npm-cache
  script:
    - ls -lrt
    - docker-compose run e2e sh ./docker/scripts/e2e_entrypoint.sh -d
  only:
    refs:
      - cron
    when:
      schedule:
        - cron: "30 14 * * *"
  tags:
    - clusterv2
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/e2e_output/e2e_output/e2e_output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define the schedule in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. You have to create the schedule using the UI: CI/CD, Schedules, New schedule.

In `.gitlab-ci-yml` you have to specify that the job should run when the pipeline is triggered by a schedule. Example from [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#run-jobs-for-scheduled-pipelines):

```yaml
job:on-schedule:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
  script:
    - make world
```

The use of `rules` is preferred over `only`/`except`.